# JS/jQuery for assigning values

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I am trying to achieve this:

1. Currently value has been set on 2 radio buttons.
2. Once one of the button is selected, the value(attribute) of that button should be assigned to the value of the div with an id.

I am not sure where I am going wrong. Below is the code snippet.

```js
var init_font_one = $('input[id="init-one-name"]'),
  init_font_two = $('input[id="init-two-name"]'),
  init_id_value = $("#test");

if (init_font_one == 'checked') {
  init_id_value.val(init_font_one.val());
}

if (init_font_two == 'checked') {
  init_id_value.val(init_font_two.val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="test" value="abc"> Testing
<input id="init-one-name" type="radio" name="init-one-name" value="abcd"><label>Test1</label>
<input id="init-two-name" type="radio" name="init-one-name" value="xyz"><label>Test2</label>
```

Comment: `if(init_font_one.prop('checked'))` Use `.prop()` to get properties `init_font_one == 'checked'` will never be _true_

Comment: `div` does not have property `value`. Use hidden input fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `on('change'` to update the value of div when radio button is click. And use `attr` of jQuery to update the value of particular element.

Try this.

```js
var init_font_one = $('input[id="init-one-name"]'),
    init_font_two = $('input[id="init-two-name"]'),
    init_id_value = $("#test");

init_font_one.change(function() {
  init_id_value.attr("value",init_font_one.val());
  console.log(init_id_value.attr("value"));
});

init_font_two.on('change',function() {
  init_id_value.attr("value",init_font_two.val());
  console.log(init_id_value.attr("value"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test" value="abc">
 Testing
 </div>
 
 <input id="init-one-name" type="radio" name="init-one-name" value="abcd"><label>Test1</label>
  
        <input id="init-two-name" type="radio" name="init-one-name" value="xyz"><label>Test2</label>
```

Comment: This worked for me. Others didn't. But I'm sure others were correct too but there was something which I didn't mention clearly.

Comment: I used .change before, didn't work. But on('change worked. Why is that?

Comment: @NaveenLBhandari you have to sent your code snippet(there must be some other problem), because it's working for me(see the code, I used both method and both works)

Answer (score 1):

There is few problems with your code:

1. `<div>` can't have `value` property.
2. Your code executes on page load and not when some event was triggered.
3. `init_font_one == 'checked'` compares jQuery object with string.
4. `input[id="init-one-name"]` can be replaced with `#init-one-name`
5. Your labels are not linked with inputs.

```js
$('.radios').change(function() {
  $("#test").val($('.radios:checked').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <!-- uncomment below -->
  <!--<input type="hidden" id="test" value="abc"/>-->
  <input type="text" id="test" value="abc" /> Testing
</div>

<input class="radios" id="init-one-name" type="radio" name="init-one-name" value="abcd"><label for="init-one-name">Test1</label>

<input class="radios" id="init-two-name" type="radio" name="init-one-name" value="xyz"><label for="init-two-name">Test2</label>
```

Comment: Explanation of above issues are useful for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("input[type='button']").click(function(){
            var radioValue = 
$("input[name='init-one-name']:checked").val();
            if(radioValue){
                alert("Your are a - " + radioValue);
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: Explain what to *try*

Comment: @Justinas there is nothing to explain its simple JQuery code

Answer (score 0):

You should use jQuery `change event` to detect the change in the radio buttons and assign the value of checked radio button to the div with id="test"

```js
var init_id_value = $("#test");

$('input[id="init-one-name"]').on('change', function() {
  init_id_value.text($(this).val());
});
$('input[id="init-two-name"]').on('change', function() {
  init_id_value.text($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test" value="abc">
 Testing
 </div>
 
 <input id="init-one-name" type="radio" name="init-one-name" value="abcd"><label>Test1</label>
  
        <input id="init-two-name" type="radio" name="init-one-name" value="xyz"><label>Test2</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand what you are trying to do, but try this:

```js
$( "input[name='init-one-name']" ).change(function(){
  $('#test').val('New Value: ' + $(this).val());
});
```

```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <textarea id="test">Testing
    </textarea><BR>
     
     <input type="radio" name="init-one-name" value="abcd"><label>Op 1</label>
      <input type="radio" name="init-one-name" value="xyz"><label>OP 2</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no value on a div, but you can change the text content or you can assing a "virtual value" to the div using .data()

Check the snippet

```js
$(function(){ // On jquery initialize
  var idtest = $('#test'); // the target Div
 $('input[type="radio"]').on('change',function(){ // change event for the two radio buttons
    
     /*** Method 1 : Using data attribute to assing a value ***/
     idtest.data('value',$(this).val()); // Value of the selected radio
   
     /*** Method 2 : Add the value of the selected radio to the text inside the div ***/
     idtest.text( $(this).val() ) // Value of the selected radio
     
     //retrieve the setted data value
     console.log( idtest.data('value') );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test" value="abc">
 Testing
</div>
 
 <input id="init-one-name" type="radio" name="init-one-name" value="abcd"><label>Test1</label>
  
 <input id="init-two-name" type="radio" name="init-one-name" value="xyz"><label>Test2</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the fixed code below.
**Added a listener to detect action performed over the radio buttons and changed method to check if radio is checked or not.**

```js
let ele = document.getElementById('init-one-div');
ele.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if ("INPUT" === e.target.nodeName)
    checkAndAssign();
});

function checkAndAssign() {
  var init_font_one = $('#init-one-name'),
    init_font_two = $('#init-two-name'),
    init_id_value = $("#test");

  if (init_font_one.is(':checked')) {
    init_id_value.val(init_font_one.val());
  }

  if (init_font_two.is(':checked')) {
    init_id_value.val(init_font_two.val());
  }

  //REMOVE below line if you want to remove the line printing the result
  init_id_value.html(' Testing [ ' + init_id_value.val() + ' ] ');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test" value="abc">
  Testing
</div>

<div id="init-one-div">
  <input id="init-one-name" type="radio" name="init-one-name" value="abcd"> <label>Test1</label>

  <input id="init-two-name" type="radio" name="init-one-name" value="xyz"> <label>Test2</label>
</div>
```